# Laravel: how to check middleware in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

i've created Middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware isTeacher
```

in App/Http/isTeacher.php i've placed the check:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class isTeacher
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user && $user->capability == 3)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }
    else
        return redirect('/login');
  }
}
```

than, i've defined the middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'auth.teacher' => \App\Http\Middleware\isTeacher::class,
    ...
];
```

The question is: how I check the teacher capability in blade template?
I'm trying with this:

```
@if (Auth::isTeacher())
```

but doesn't work

any help are appreciated

Comment: The answer you've already received is correct in that middleware is not appropriate for your use case, however, instead of using sessions you should be looking at using Policies for this, here's the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization

Answer (score 10):

The blade directive only needs to return true or false, nothing else.

You could just do the following in the `boot()` method of the `AppServiceProvider.php`

```html
Blade::if('teacher', function () {
    return auth()->user() && $user->capability == 3;
});
```

Then you will be able to do the following in blade templates:

```html
@teacher
  Only teachers will see this
@endteacher
```

Answer (score 3):

Well there is an issue here Middlewares are used to filter `HTTP` requests or its outter layer of the onion in laravel app. It is not defined to be used in blade to decide which part of html should be rendered.

You can filter a controller function to only be usable if it passes the middleware (if authenticated for example) and the controller only runs the function if it passes on the middleware.

When using `Auth` in blades you are not using a middleware but a `facade` whan you could do its use `Session` for your case like:

In your middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class isTeacher
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $user = Auth::user();

    if($user && $user->capability == 3)
    {
        \session('isTeacher', true);
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/login');

}
```

Then in your blades do like:

```
@if (Session::get('isTeacher', 0));
```

This will show content only to teachers, if session its not set it will fall back to 0 or false.

Comment: thank you, this code is working correctly. My doubt is: when user logged out, session "isTeacher" remains?

Comment: Logout session in flush it! Why did you remove my answer   ? @mariobros

Answer (score 2):

This is an improved version of Prince Lionel's answer. Pay attention to the return value of Blade::directive callback function.

```
@author
    //Do something
@else
    //Something else
@endauthor
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('author', function () {
            $isAuth = false;

            // check if the user authenticated is teacher
            if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->capability == 3) {

                $isAuth = true;
            }

            return "<?php if (" . intval($isAuth) . ") { ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endauthor', function () {
            return "<?php } ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, using middleware is not really the solution. I will rather suggest blade directive, which allows you to create a custom blade function like:

```
@author
    //Do something
@else
    //Something else
@endauthor
```

To use the above syntax, you can register a new blade directive in your AppServiceProvider.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('author', function () {
            $isAuth = false;

            // check if the user authenticated is teacher
            if (auth()->user() && auth()->user()->capability == 3) {

                $isAuth = true;
            }

            return "<?php if ($isAuth) { ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endauthor', function () {
            return "<?php } ?>";
        });
    }
}
```

After the above changes in the `AppServiceProvider.php` file, run `php artisan view:clear`

For a better understanding, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade)

Comment: please can you give reason why this approach dos not look great ?

Comment: thanks, but this code doesn't work. Blade return an error on if condition.

Comment: This answer will not work when `$isAuth == false`. Because Boolean value`false` will be converted to an empty string, So you'll have a code like this in your blade, which will obviously produce an error
```<?php if () { ?>```